# Is there any benefit to switching to ESM if I am already using TypeScript in my Node.js service

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules

My current use-case is that I use `node-fetch` in my service and the recent version of `node-fetch` (3.x) is a [pure ESM module](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#commonjs) which means that I am gonna be stuck to v2.x and will not be able to update it.

My options are either to convert my service to ESM from CJS or switch to some other HTTP client such as axios. Both the options require a lot of efforts and I am trying to see which option make more sense.

So my question is is there any benefit of switching to ESM from CJS if the service is already written in TypeScript?

Comment: I don't get the problem with sticking with v2. It always worked great for me and they say they will still provide bug fixes.

Comment: The benefits from ESM outweigh CJS and the work to switch from CJS. You can see just a *handful* of them in this [blog post](https://pawelgrzybek.com/all-you-need-to-know-to-move-from-commonjs-to-ecmascript-modules-esm-in-node-js/). TypeScript works better with ESM anyways (type inferencing). Besides, it's not even that much work to switch.

Comment: @zoran404 It's frowned upon by internal tooling to continue using old versions when the new one is available. Additionally, we're gonna miss on new features in the future (not sure what they are). Currently we're sticking with v2, but I wanted to justify any such decision.

Comment: @kelly I already checked the blogpost before, but I still didn't get any immediate benefit. It's a big service and need non-trivial amount of time to switch (I have tried spending some time there already and realised that it does need some more work). That's why I wanted to justify (mostly myself) spending more time to make the switch.

Comment: Idk what to tell you. For me `node-fetch` seems like too small of a dependency to be worth converting my projects. And if there is a new feature that I need, I'd rather look for a different node module.